# Creating Custom List Definitions that Use InfoPath Forms - Deploy everything using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: web-part, list, infopath, visual-studio, list-definition

I'm trying to create a list instance from a list definition, all from a VS2010 solution and want to have custom InfoPath forms for the list instance.

This article keeps popping around in my searches: http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/walkthrough-deploying-a-infopath-2010-list-form-in-a-visual-studio-2010-solution-package/

But it does not work. It seems the `BrowserFormWebPart` web parts don't contain the correct stuff to match the specific content type ID.

I've created lists with the UI, designed the forms, exported the list as template and looked inside the files to see how to create different parts etc etc etc. Nothing works.

Is that the only way to deploy customized InfoPath forms? Has someone managed to make it work? Is there some "gotcha"s I need to be aware of?

What other options do I have?